# Unable to set dropdown boundary in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I had the following markup working in Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span type="button" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="viewport">
        <img src="~/images/menu.png" title="Menu" />
    </span>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I upgraded to Bootstrap 5, the dropdown no longer opens.

I figured out that I need to change the `data-toggle` attribute to use the `data-bs-toggle` attribute instead. Now the dropdown works.

However, the `data-boundary="viewport"` attribute no longer works. This attribute allows the dropdown to extend outside the container element. As it is now, the dropdown is cut off when its bounds fall outside of the container.

I tried using `data-bs-boundary="viewport"` and `data-bs-boundary="body"` as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098157/bootstrap-5-1-3-dropdown-data-bs-boundary-no-longer-works).

Does anyone know how to use this attribute in Bootstrap 5?

**Update:**

This is how Bootstrap is included in a new project created by Visual Studio.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TempAspNet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/TempAspNet.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append the bootstrap 5 dropdown menu to a specific element. when the dropdown element is inside an element with overflow: hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031318/how-to-append-the-bootstrap-5-dropdown-menu-to-a-specific-element-when-the-drop)

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

**1. Change the Popper version via CDN**

According to the most upvoted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098157/bootstrap-5-1-3-dropdown-data-bs-boundary-no-longer-works) question, this happens because of the Popper version. Boostrap 4.6 uses `Popper 1.16.1` ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/)) while Bootstrap 5 uses `Popper 2.9.2` ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)). Try changing the Popper version.

**2. Take a look at the Popper docs**

Try setting the area to something other than the `body` ([link](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/utils/detect-overflow/#boundary)).

Let me know if this is helpful.

---

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Popper version from Bootstrap 4.6 -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how do I override the version of Popper that Bootstrap is using?

Comment: I updated my answer. Not really sure if this will be of any help. I see that you were asking the other guy with the same problem and yet no solution was found. Try and let me know.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm clearly missing something. Right now, I have Bootstrap working fine (aside from the data-bs-boundary issue). And I don't see any references to popper. It's hard to understand how you are overriding something that doesn't get referenced.

Comment: Please update your question with a screenshot of your HTML where you add Bootstrap into your project. Popper is definitely referenced, but maybe in a bundle (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Comment: I've added the markup to my question. This is the markup created automatically by Visual Studio when creating an ASP.NET Core web application.

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap JS isn't added inside the `<head>`, only CSS. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET. Try to find where Bootstrap JS is added to your ASP.NET project. It has to be somewhere, otherwise Bootstrap animations/effects would not work, only styles. This might help you: https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client-side/bootstrap.html